# Export / Import Orders

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, import, export

We have a site that has been in development and need to update the order information from the current live site.

Is it possible to just export a number of the tables from the current live site and import into the dev site? If so, can anyone tell me which tables I need to export?

Answer (score 2):

Sales Order depends on both Customers & Products, so, it'll be better if you can export the whole database to dev site.

Otherwise if you already have same Products and Customers in Dev site, then try exporting following tables:

**SALES RELATED TABLES**

`sales_flat_creditmemo`;

`sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`;

`sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`;

`sales_flat_creditmemo_item`;

`sales_flat_invoice`;

`sales_flat_invoice_comment`;

`sales_flat_invoice_grid`;

`sales_flat_invoice_item`;

`sales_flat_order`;

`sales_flat_order_address`;

`sales_flat_order_grid`;

`sales_flat_order_item`;

`sales_flat_order_payment`;

`sales_flat_order_status_history`;

`sales_flat_quote`;

`sales_flat_quote_address`;

`sales_flat_quote_address_item`;

`sales_flat_quote_item`;

`sales_flat_quote_item_option`;

`sales_flat_quote_payment`;

`sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`;

`sales_flat_shipment`;

`sales_flat_shipment_comment`;

`sales_flat_shipment_grid`;

`sales_flat_shipment_item`;

`sales_flat_shipment_track`;

`sales_invoiced_aggregated`;

`sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;

`log_quote`;